# How to tell which block guard exits out of?

Tags: swift, scope, swift3, swift-guard

When `guard` fails the condition, they exit the closure. However, what confuses me what is considered to be a block the guard exits out of?

For example, if I have the following:

```
func doThing() {
  while ... {
    for ... {
      if ... {
        guard ... else { return }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does the `guard` exit just the `if`, `for`, `while`, or entire `func`?

What is the actual rule because I've read `block` and `closure` terms used interchangeably when defining what the `guard` exits out of, but each term implicate things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` statement used to exit from nearest closure (function in your case) with result value (`Void` by default), no matter how deep you are in cycles or `if` conditions. Probably you mixed up `return` with `break`.

However, you may also use `break`, `continue` or `throw` statement in `else` clause of `guard` statement. If you use `break` statement, for example, you end execution of nearest cycle or `switch` statement, or, if you [mark cycle/`if`/`switch` by label](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID141) and use `break` followed with that label, you exit marked statement.